# How to monitor syscalls being called by a user on FreeBSD using auditing?

Tags: freebsd, configuration, audit

I would like to monitor every syscall being called on my FreeBSD using `auditd`. I know it is possible on Linux but I cannot 
find any information on how I should configure FreeBSD.

**Is it even possible to monitor every system call in FreeBSD?**

---

#### Detaills

My `/etc/security/audit_control` looks like this 
at the moment:

```
#
# $FreeBSD: releng/10.3/contrib/openbsm/etc/audit_control 293161 2016-01-04 16:32:21Z brueffer $
#
dir:/var/audit
dist:off
flags:lo,aa
minfree:5
naflags:lo,aa
policy:cnt,argv
filesz:2M
expire-after:10M
```

Flags are set to audit everything and the policy 
is set to record command line to `execve(2)` 
(see `audit_control(5)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like there was a typo in my `/etc/security/audit_control`:

```
#
# $FreeBSD: releng/10.3/contrib/openbsm/etc/audit_control 293161 2016-01-04 16:32:21Z brueffer $
#
dir:/var/audit
dist:off
flags:all
minfree:5
naflags:all
policy:cnt,argv,arge,seq,
filesz:2M
expire-after:10M
```

This configuration produces insane amount of audit trails.

In Linux Audit they are present in `a0`, `a1`, `a2` and `a3` fields explicitly while in the OpenBSM format they are stored in the argument tokens (see `audit.log(5)`).

For example:

> ```
> header,108,11,close(2),0,Mon Aug 15 01:47:53 2016, + 865 msec
> argument,1,0x6,fd
> attribute,644,root,wheel,88,3148396,6394391
> subject,-1,root,wheel,root,wheel,1721,0,0,0.0.0.0
> return,success,0
> trailer,108
> ```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or an update?  If it's an update then please edit the original question and delete this answer.

Comment: @StephenHarris It is a partial answer to my question. From what I see I am able to monitor a lot of syscalls. However, I am still not sure if I am auditing all the possible information about the system calls.